# grep -e in solaris complaining (/usr/xpg4/bin/grep)

Tags: ruby, shell, solaris

I have a simple shell command in the ruby script.

```
command="cat file_name | grep -e 'text1 text2.*'"
```

It is working fine on AIX and Linux but failing on SOLARIS. I tried to see which grep is it using and it returned `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` which looks good to me. Please let me know what else can be causing the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In all probability your user's PATH is different from your script's. On solaris `/usr/bin/grep` does not support `-e` but `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` does. Adjust the PATH in effect for the script to place the xpg4 bin dir ahead of the other one.

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris I would suggest to be sure to use GNU grep. (since you're keen on using the -e option)

If you are on **Solaris 10**:  GNU grep is installed by default but may not be part of your PATH because it lives in `/usr/sfw/bin`.  The name of the binary is `ggrep`.

If you are on **Solaris 11**:  GNU grep is installed by default on global zones but will not make its way into local zones by default. If installed it will already be in your PATH but just like on Solaris 10 it is called `ggrep`. If not installed then simply do `pkg install gnu-grep`.

To make your script portable you can do something like this in the beginning of your script:

```
# Default values
GREP=grep
EGREP=egrep

if [ `uname` == "SunOS" ]; then
  GREP=ggrep
  EGREP=gegrep
fi
```

.. and then everywhere in your script you refer to $GREP when you want to execute 'grep' and so on.